# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll in WPF telerik TreeView Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, telerik

Here is my xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <sampleData:MainWindow  x:Key="DataSource"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomComponentParameter">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="CustomComponent" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomComponentParameter}"
       ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters }">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

for the telerik control

```
    <telerik:RadTreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataSource},Path=SummaryViewCollection}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomComponent}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="77" Margin="345,482,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="449">

    </telerik:RadTreeView>
```

Here is my Codebehind classes

Code for the main Codebehind Class MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
    public ObservableCollection<CustomComponent> SummaryViewCollection { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {          
       this.SummaryViewCollection = //code to fill in the details 
    }           
 }
```

Here is the code for CustomComponentClass

```
public class CustomComponent
{

    private ObservableCollection<CustomComponentParameter> parameters = new ObservableCollection<CustomComponentParameter>();


    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;        
    }     

    public ObservableCollection<CustomComponentParameter> Parameters
    {
        get
        {
            return this.parameters;
        }

        set
        {
            this.parameters = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Code for the CustomComponentParameter Class

```
public class CustomComponentParameter
{       
    public string Name
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public bool HasErrors
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public bool IsDuplicate
    {
        get;set;
    }


    public bool IsMissing
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

Everytime i run it  i get the following error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll". Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.
Any suggestion on this? Thanks

Comment: Why are you setting an ItemTemplate? I don't see in a need in doing that in your code.

Comment: If all the `//code to fill in the details` is disabled do you still get the exception? Somewhere you've got something calling itself repeatedly when you're trying to start up.

Comment: <dumb-question>Is there a stack trace that shows us where it starts in your code when you catch the exception in a debugger?</dumb-question>

Comment: Need to know which line is throwing that exception.  In VS Debug, Exception, CLR, thrown.  Then just run it in debug.  If the error is not obvious then look at the stack trace.

Comment: @gleng which Item Template are you referring to?

Comment: @Craig Graham  I tested the code to fill in the details it returns the list of data

Comment: @Jeff there isn't at the moment thats why this question exist.. this is all i get from vs 2012 "{Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}"

Comment: Doesn't quite answer the question :) In the absence of anything obvious in what I can see, the first step I'd consider is disabling everything else and seeing when it stops throwing the exception. I've never seen a stack overflow from pure xaml and empty properties and constructors.

Comment: Thanks Craig i'll do as you say.

Comment: @Sike12 You might put a breakpoint on the "first line of code" that runs in your application, and `F11` through the code until it goes away into oblivion ;)

Comment: @Blam i cant get the stacktrace for some wierd reason. thanks for the info

Comment: @craiggraham a Stackoverflow may occur from pure XAML if you create and endless nested UI element sequence, for example `ContentPresenterA` -> `ContentPresenterB` -> `ContentPresenterB.Content = ContentPresenterA` or something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stackoverflow exception is occuring because you are creating the instance of `MainWindow` in `MainWindow's` `Resources` by doing `<sampleData:MainWindow  x:Key="DataSource"/>` which is sending the program into infinite recursion

If you want to set the `DataContext` of window to self then remove this line and in the constructor of your `MainWindow` do

```
public MainWindow()
{          
   InitializeComponents();
   this.SummaryViewCollection = //code to fill in the details 
   DataContext = this;
}
```

and then your binding will be just

```
 <telerik:RadTreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SummaryViewCollection}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomComponent}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="77" Margin="345,482,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="449">

</telerik:RadTreeView>
```

Comment: Hi Nit. That solved the exception issue but the control is not visible in the UI now. can't we do something like set the datacontext of the treeview to SummaryViewCollection in the codebehind (even this doesn't work though). :)

Comment: can you check if you are getting any binding errors in output window?

Comment: No i am not seeing any binding errors. its just that the treeview doesnt appear. i believe it only appears if the binding is correct.

Comment: Hi @Nit apologies for the delay. The Value for the ItemSource needs to be just {Binding} because the treeView's DataContext  is set to the collection in the codebehind. treeeView Control itself in the codehind. I have updated you code and will approve it as a accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

In my case, an extra call to DataBind() was causing this exception. Removing that extra call fixed the issue.